# How to escape this ± character in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using charset=utf-8 character encoding and I am getting a weird symbol when I use "±" in my code.  I am trying to output a text string like this:

```
.text('GMT Standard Time (UTC ±0)')
```

but I am getting this instead: GMT Standard Time (UTC �0)

What is the weird question mark character for? How to escape and properly display ± instead?

Comment: Are you *sure* your page is using UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Yes, this is in my source:  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: You don’t need _escaping_, you need _**proper** encoding_. UTF-8 must be **everywhere**: your text file must be stored as UTF-8, the HTML needs to be served as UTF-8, [`<meta charset="UTF-8">`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-charset) needs to be used.

Comment: The `meta` tag just declares what encoding is used. But it can lie. I can save a file in EBCIDC and use a `meta` tag that says it's UTF-8. Also note the `http-equiv` value; that means that tag is being used instead of an appropriate HTTP header. The web server should be in charge of setting the appropriate `Content-Type` header.

Comment: @SebastianSimon you are absolutely right. I re-saved the js file with notepad as utf-8 and now it's working fine.  Thank you! :D

Comment: `.html('GMT Standard Time (UTC &plusmn;0)')`

Comment: @SebastianSimon I'll accept your insight if you post it as an answer. Thanks again.